# Using Make to create DPKG .debs always rebuilds, not when files have changed

Tags: makefile, packaging

This is a slightly odd one where I'm sure I'm missing something perfectly straightforward.

I'm trying to cut some of the cruft off our build time, part of that is rebuilding a set of .debs we use which occurs everytime we've changed an aspect of the system due to the way an ant script has been configured. I was hoping to use Makefiles to monitor the folders that are going to be used for the dpkg process, so only the directories that have had recent changes are recreated but:

```
build-printing:
               fakeroot dpkg -b printing printing.deb
```

Is constantly rerun, even though the files in that specific directory haven't changed. I'm sure I've missed something really simple, but I can't spot it in the man pages.

Comment: your `build-printing` rule doesn't depend on anything - tell it which files it should watch the timestamps of

Comment: Andddd thats it. Knew I was missing something simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build-printing rule doesn't depend on anything - tell it which files it should watch the timestamps of, e.g.:

```
build-printing: directory/myfile.src
        ....
```

will cause build-printing to only be run if the time stamp on directoy/myfile.src is newer than the timestamp of build-printing. Since the rule doesn't look like it actually creates build-printing as a file you probably want to rename it to match the output file, e..g.

```
printing.deb: directory/myfile.src
        ....
```

If you want to use a rule named build-printing you can either make that rule touch a file called build-printing, or make that rule depend upon printing.deb.